# Amazon AWS: DataPipelineDefaultRole/EDPSession not authorized to perform iam:ListRolePolicies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-data-pipeline

I have been assigned an IAM role in AWS by my manager and I am trying to setup an Amazon Data Pipeline. I am repeatedly facing permission issues and authorization issues like the following when trying to activate the PipeLine.

> WARNING: Error occured while validating role
>   'DataPipelineDefaultRole'. Error: Status Code: 403, AWS Service:
>   AmazonIdentityManagement, AWS Request ID:
>   fbf1935a-bcf1-11e3-82d4-cd47aac2f228, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied,
>   AWS Error Message: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::723751385540:assumed-role/DataPipelineDefaultRole/EDPSession
>   is not authorized to perform: iam:ListRolePolicies on resource: role
>   DataPipelineDefaultRole

There are no errors... only warnings like the one above.

My CTO has assigned me with Super Administrator Role in the AWS access manager. Yet i am not able to do it. Been at least 2 weeks that we are going around this thing. He has granted all super admin permissions and privileges to my IAM.

p.s. i followed the documentation of "***Export RDS data to S3 via CopyActivity using the AWS Data Pipeline console***" tutorial from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-mysql-console.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and could find a solution in the following AWS documentation link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-iam-roles.html

I quote the text that solved the issue:

> **Update Existing IAM Roles for AWS Data Pipeline**
>
> Use the following procedure to update the `DataPipelineDefaultRole` and `DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole` roles.
>
> To update your existing IAM roles using managed policies
>
> Open the Identity and Access Management console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/
>
> Update the `DataPipelineDefaultRole` role as follows:
>
> 1. In the navigation pane, click Roles, and then click the row for the `DataPipelineDefaultRole` role.
> 2. Under Permissions, click Attach Policy.
> 3. On the Attach Policy page, click the box next to the `AWSDataPipelineRole` policy, and then click Attach Policy.
>
> Update the `DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole` role as follows:
>
> 1. In the navigation pane, click Roles, and then click the row for the `DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole` role
> 2. Under Permissions, click Attach Policy.
> 3. On the Attach Policy page, click the box next to the `AmazonEC2RoleForDataPipelineRole` policy, and then click Attach Policy.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are using DataPipelineDefaultRole as datapipeline role. Make sure it has permissions to listPolicies - Go to aws console. Checkout the policy for the role and make sure it has the required permissions

Also, if it is just warnings, they should not be a blocker. I would suggest you to continue activating your pipeline. Once, pipeline is activated, refer the datapipeline trouble shooting docs - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-troubleshooting.html in case of any issues. My personal tip would be to enable logUri - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-error-logs.html since it makes debugging the failed activity easier.

Comment: hi @Himanshu, i tried what you mentioned but looks like DataPipelineDefaultRole already had ListRolePolicies permission. I have updated the warning message that i actually got. Do you still think the problem is with DataPipelineDefaultRole or is it somewhere else? the IAM is getting very tricky.